# DataFrame getting columns with indexes and slicing

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame and I want to get a new one with some columns of it.
I'm using `pandas.DataFrame.iloc()` and I want to get, for example, 1st and 3rd to 98th columns.
I know I can use only indexes in `iloc()`: `new_df = df.iloc[:, [1, 3, 4, ..., 99]]` or slicing: `new_df = df.iloc[:, 3:99]` but how to combine them?

Of course, there are many ways to do it:
e.g. `new_df = df.iloc[:, 3:99].drop(df.columns[1], axis=1)`,
but is there a way to do it only with `iloc()` function? I want to get the shortest solution possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found such a solution but I'm still interested if there is another, shorter way:
`new_df = df.iloc[:, [1] + list(range(3,99))]`.

I can achive that with `numpy.r_` too:
`new_df = df.iloc[:, np.r_[1, 3:99]]`.